# How do I get a users email from the SoundCloud API?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am using SoundCloud as a sign-on method using their OAuth2 API, for my own app.

I can sign in and grab personal information from the authenticated user, but how do I access the email address? If at all possible?

A typical response looks like:

```
{
  "id": 3207,
  "permalink": "jwagener",
  "username": "Johannes Wagener",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207",
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/jwagener",
  "avatar_url": "http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000001552142-pbw8yd-large.jpg?142a848",
  "country": "Germany",
  "full_name": "Johannes Wagener",
  "city": "Berlin",
  "description": "<b>Hacker at SoundCloud</b>\r\n\r\nSome of my recent Hacks:\r\n\r\nsoundiverse.com \r\nbrowse recordings with the FiRe app by artwork\r\n\r\ntopbillin.com \r\nfind people to follow on SoundCloud\r\n\r\nchatter.fm \r\nget your account hooked up with a voicebox\r\n\r\nrecbutton.com \r\nrecord straight to your soundcloud account",
  "discogs_name": null,
  "myspace_name": null,
  "website": "http://johannes.wagener.cc",
  "website_title": "johannes.wagener.cc",
  "online": true,
  "track_count": 12,
  "playlist_count": 1,
  "followers_count": 416,
  "followings_count": 174,
  "public_favorites_count": 26,
  "plan": "Pro Plus",
  "private_tracks_count": 63,
  "private_playlists_count": 3,
  "primary_email_confirmed": true
}
```

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me

Is there a way to request further information if the user grants me permission to do so? I cannot see where / how to do this, from reading their API docs. Google searching isn't revealing much (possibly because it's not that popular as an API yet) either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: its not possible. imagine what will happen if everyone have access to email addresses of the soundcloud users.

Comment: Well, not much. You can get emails from Facebook users in a standard request. You just have to ask the user for permission - which seems fair. I was wondering if it was possible by certain permissions?

Comment: yeah, that 'just ask the user for permission' is the key. there is no such thing on soundcloud. even if the user connects to your app with soundcloud account (and allow access to your app), user email is not in the /me response.

Comment: @cucko It's a shame isn't it? I will have to drop SoundCloud as an authentication service, as prompting the user there-after would be too inconvenient and break the whole 'ease of use' for them. 

For the record, Facebook and Google+ API's do allow you access to a user email. Nice! Twitter, SoundCloud and Reddit API's do not; but even worse, completely lack the mechanism to even ask for permission at all.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: yes, it's a shame. i'm using soundcloud api long time and i'm disappointed with theirs docs too. they're changing methods and filters without any notice. p.s. if you're using tracks search filters be aware: tags, genre and maybe duration filters are not working.

Comment: ...and not to mention that they don't reply on my emails. even when is bug report on soundcloud.com.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo Reddit doesn't require an email address to register an account so why would you think it would be available from their API?

Comment: @idbehold But you can still provide an email to obtain an authenticated account. I know that most do not have them.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo  After a long time i also need users email address but SoundCloud does't have any good lack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get a user's email address using the [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference).